# Does hf14b raw command allow me to send and receive APDU messages?

Tags: rfid, apdu, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

Undocumented in the Proxmark3's Wiki as well as in its command-line documentation, the proxmark3 Linux client provides the `hf 14a apdu` command (though there is no `hf 14b apdu` command).

The way I view things is that APDU build on top of ISO14443. ISO14443's anti-collision and selection protocol can be implemented using `hf 14a raw` or `hf 14b raw` command.

After selecting my chip using the `raw` command, can I simply send and receive APDU messages using the same command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't be able to use `hf 14a apdu` after you selected a card with `hf 14b raw`. The problem is that the command `hf 14a apdu` will use ISO/IEC 14443 Type A coding and framing (including CRC). Since Type B uses a different coding, framing and CRC, the Type B card would not be able to understand what you sent. However, you can easily wrap your APDU commands into raw Type B frames by prepending the PCB (which in most cases is just alternating between 0x02 and 0x03). Waiting time extension and other elements of the ISO-DEP protocol may be a bit more tricky though.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know how the chip can be selected using `hf 14b raw`?

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews Doesn't that work with the -s option (just as for `hf 14a raw`)? At least that's what the usage docs suggest.

Comment: Sounds like it does, thanks! I didn't understand that's what the doc meant.